# pandas using a variable number of or statements

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, operators

I want to produce a simple filter:

```
fil = (df['col'] == cond 1) | (df['col'] == cond 2) | (df['col'] == cond 3)
```

however, the number of conditions varies. So in another case, the filter would look like:

```
fil = (df['col'] == cond 1) | (df['col'] == cond 2)
```

or

```
fil = (df['col'] == cond 1) | (df['col'] == cond 2) | (df['col'] == cond 3) | (df['col'] == cond 4)
```

The conditions themselves are available as a list, i.e.:

```
condList = [cond 1, cond 2, cond 3]
```

or

```
condList = [cond 1, cond 2]
```

or

```
condList = [cond 1, cond 2, cond 3, cond 3]
```

So I would like to have a filter that would somehow look like:

```
fil = df['col'] == or(condList)
```

Comment: You can use .isin([list_of_values]) function. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html

Comment: Are the conditions always as you say i.e. always `==` and combined using `|`?

Comment: @Tom actually no. Sometimes it is also e.g., xxx.str.contains(cond 1) | xxx.str.contains(cond 2) – and I am not sure .isin then works (which is great otherwise).

Comment: I am not sure it is possible then (but someone may prove me wrong). If the conditions used, for example, depended on the length of `condList` then I guess you could call different functions applying the condition depending on `len(condList)`. However without such dependence, I am not sure how you would proceed.